# Generic one-to-many relationship with constructor

Tags: hibernate, jpa, constructor, annotations, lombok

I have an entity that uses a generic one-to-many relationship. Unfortunately, the lobmok *@AllArgsConstructor*, fails to map/cast a *List<? extends Translatable>* to a *List< EducationTranslation>*.
The properties of EducationTranslation and Translatable are exactly the same and EducationTranslation **extends** Translatable.
If I remove my custom constructor I get the following error:

> Can not set java.lang.Long field EducationTranslation.id to
> Translatable

Is there an annotation or a design pattern that would allow me to get rid of the self written constructor and keep the code cleaner and shorter?

```
@OneToMany(
    targetEntity = EducationTranslation.class,
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<? extends Translatable> translationList = new ArrayList<>();


public Education(Long id, Profile profile, Collection<? extends Translatable> translationList) {
    this.id = id;
    this.profile = profile;
    this.translationList = translationList
        .stream()
        .map(x -> new EducationTranslation(x.getId(), x.getCode(), x.getTranslation()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: (1) The 'can not set field' error is JPA complaining it cannot read/populate the `id` property of `EducationTranslation` using reflection. I highly doubt this has anything to do with `Education`'s constructor, (2) you do realize you will never be able to insert anything into a list declared as `List<? extends Translatable>`, right?

Comment: regarding (2) is this due to the unknown memory size of the object? I thought setting the targetEntity would set memory size

Comment: No, that's because of how generics work. The declaration states: 'this is a list of objects of some type that extends `Translatable`' . You cannot insert anything to such a list, because the compiler doesn' t know which specific type of objects the list accepts. Without casting, the list becomes effectively read-only once it is assigned

Comment: Well, I don't insert "anything". My EducationTranslation extends Translatable. And I sort of do a cast by my stream iteration.

Comment: Yes, your stream pipeline produces a `List<EducationTranslation>`. You then assign it to a property of type `List<? extends Translatable>`. After this point, `translationList.add(<anything>)` will produce a compile error, no mather what you put in place of `<anything>`. This is fine, because your pipeline produces an immutable list anyway, BUT if you save your entity, load it from the data store, and try to add an element, you'll *still* get a compile error. Just wanted to make sure you're aware of that

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of this. If you could reply with an answer and formulate out why I am allowed to initially add elements and save it the date store, but then get a compile error when trying to add an element using the same object signature, you would help me a lot in understanding this and you also get the check mark ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections constrained using wildcards are... somewhat inconvenient with JPA entities.

Note that after the initial creation, you will never be able to insert anything into a list declared as `List<? extends Translatable>` without casting, meaning the following code will not work:

```
Education education = entityManager.find(Education.class, id);
education.getTranslationList().add(new EducationTranslation(...)); // compilation error
```

The reason it behaves like that is that `List<? extends Translatable>` is interpreted as 'list of some unknown element type that extends `Translatable`', and the compiler cannot allow your code to add anything to such a list, not knowing what *exact* type `?` stands for. I imagine you would hope for `.add(new EducationTranslation())` to be legal, because `EducationTranslation` *does* extend `Translatable` but here is a better illustration of why it can't possibly be allowed:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Dog())); //just a mutable collection with a Dog inside
List<? extends Animal> someAnimals = dogs; //a list of Dogs is a list of 'a type that extends Animal', so - valid assignment
someAnimals.add(new Cat()); //hey, a Cat does extend Animal, so this should be legal, right?
Dog shapeshifter = dogs.get(1); //...right???
```

To sum up, it will be much more convenient to simply declare `translationList` as `List<EducationTranslation>`.

> why I am allowed to initially add elements and save it the date store, but then get a compile error when trying to add an element using the same object signature

You're not using 'the same signature'. Your code is **not** calling `.add()` at any point. It simply constructs a List whose effective type is `List<EducationTranslation>`, and then assigns it to a field declared `List<? extends Translatable>`. The problem is, you cannot call `.add(new EducationTranslation())` using the reference stored in that field, because of *the way the field is declared*, not *what you assign to it*. It's pretty much the same scenario as in the following snippet:

```
Object obj = "Hello";
obj.length(); // you know obj points to a String, but you assign it to a reference with a more general type, so this call is illegal
```

Note that if you want to hide the concrete type of the list element from a *client* of the `Education` class, then the following code is still legal:

```
interface TranslationHolder {

    List<? extends Translatable> getTranslationList();
}

class Education implements TranslationHolder {

    private List<EducationTranslation> translationList = new ArrayList<>();

    //this getter is a valid implementation for TranslationHolder.getTranslationList()
    public List<EducationTranslation> getTranslationList() {
        return translationList;
    }
}

class ClassThatUsesEducationButOnlyKnowsItAsTranslationHolder  {

   public void execute() {
        TranslationHolder holder = getEducationAsTranslationHolderInSomeIndirectWay();
        holder.getTranslationList(); // this still return a reference to List<? extends Translatable>, NOT List<EducationTranslation>
   }
}
```

So, if the point was to abstract away `EducationTranslation` from a *client* of the `Education` class, you don't need to declare the field itself as a wildcard list.

Comment: Thank you very much! Especially the dog - cat shapeshifter example was extremely well chosen and made me laugh realizing my logical error :D